# How can I split the Dart project environment as a prod, dev?

Tags: dart

I'm developing a server application with Dart(Shelf).
I want to define different settings for the prod and dev environment.

Do you know any way to achieve this?

Comment: I removed the flutter tag of your question and deleted my answer.